# API adwords EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @ > operations[0].operand

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using adwords API for java but when I try to "mutate" my campaign I get this error:
AxisFault

> faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: [EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @
>   operations[0].operand; trigger:'CampaignId: 93996448',
>   EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @ operations[1].operand;
>   trigger:'CampaignId: *******', EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @
>   operations[2].operand; trigger:'CampaignId: *******',
>   EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @ operations[3].operand;
>   trigger:'CampaignId: *******', EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @
>   operations[4].operand; trigger:'CampaignId: *******',
>   EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @ operations[5].operand;
>   trigger:'CampaignId: *******', EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @
>   operations[6].operand; trigger:'CampaignId: *******',
>   EntityNotFound.INVALID_ID @ operations[7].operand;
>   trigger:'CampaignId: *******'

I don't understand where is the problem because I've used adwords API with PHP and there never still have been problem.

I create a linkedList of "CampaignCriterionOperation" 
operations2.add(new CampaignCriterionOperation(Operator.ADD, campaignCriterionType, new CampaignCriterion(campaign.getId(), location, campaignCriterionType)));

then I mutate the campaing
CampaignCriterionOperation[] operations = new CampaignCriterionOperation[operations2.size()];
CampaignCriterionReturnValue result = campaignServiceOperation.mutate(operations2.toArray(operations));

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the CampaignId you are using in the CampaignCriterion object's isn't valid. Double check that you are using the correct IDs.